# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth not showing the complete label with visual auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel, visual-format-language

I'm trying to make with auto layout a little notification box with two labels, a progress bar, and an X to cancel. I have the labels set up the same with font scaling, but it looks like some of the labels are getting cut off. I'm not sure if it's a result of my auto layout code or my UILabel code.

[image: Issue image]

You can see that the text isn't aligned at all and the Playing in label is cut off completely.

Relevant code:

```
    // Container
    pttProgressContainer = [UIView new];
    [pttProgressContainer setBackgroundColor:UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0x3a4362, 0.10)];
    [pttProgressContainer setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [pttContainer addSubview:pttProgressContainer];

    // Separator
    UIView *progressContainer1pxView = [UIView new];
    [progressContainer1pxView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [progressContainer1pxView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [pttProgressContainer addSubview:progressContainer1pxView];

    // Progress viewzlers
    UIView *progressViewLeft = [UIView new];
    [progressViewLeft setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [pttProgressContainer addSubview:progressViewLeft];
    UIView *progressViewRight = [UIView new];
    [progressViewRight setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [pttProgressContainer addSubview:progressViewRight];

    // Progress view
    pttProgressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
    [pttProgressView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [pttProgressView setProgress:0.5 animated:NO];
    [pttProgressView setTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.20]];
    [pttProgressView setProgressTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xd7d7d7)];
    [[pttProgressView layer] setCornerRadius:5];
    [[pttProgressView layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [pttProgressView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [progressViewLeft addSubview:pttProgressView];

    // Now the playing in label countdown
    UILabel *pttPlayingInLabel = [UILabel new];
    [pttPlayingInLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    [pttPlayingInLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [pttPlayingInLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:8/20];
    [pttPlayingInLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [pttPlayingInLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [pttPlayingInLabel setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    [pttPlayingInLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [pttPlayingInLabel setText:@"Playing In..."];
    [progressViewLeft addSubview:pttPlayingInLabel];

    // Countdown numbers
    pttPlayingCountdownLabel = [UILabel new];
    [pttPlayingCountdownLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    [pttPlayingCountdownLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:8/20];
    [pttPlayingCountdownLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [pttPlayingCountdownLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    [pttPlayingCountdownLabel setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    [pttPlayingCountdownLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [pttPlayingCountdownLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [pttPlayingCountdownLabel setText:@"5"];
    [progressViewLeft addSubview:pttPlayingCountdownLabel];

    // The button del cancel
    pttCancelPlayingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [pttCancelPlayingButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [pttCancelPlayingButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ptt-button-delay-cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    [pttCancelPlayingButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
//    [pttCancelPlayingButton setTitle:@"C" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [progressViewRight addSubview:pttCancelPlayingButton];

    // Progress danker
    [pttProgressContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[progressContainer1pxView(==1)]-[progressViewLeft]-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:metrics
                                                                           views:views]];
    /*
    [pttProgressContainer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:progressViewRight
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:progressViewLeft
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0]];
    [pttProgressContainer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:progressViewRight
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:progressViewLeft
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0]];
     */

    // Visual horizontal
    [pttProgressContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[progressContainer1pxView]|"
                                                                                 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                                                                 metrics:metrics
                                                                                   views:views]];
    [pttProgressContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[progressViewLeft]-[progressViewRight(==40)]-|"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop
                                                                         metrics:metrics
                                                                           views:views]];

    // Inner danker
    [progressViewLeft addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[pttPlayingInLabel]-[pttProgressView(==3)]-|"
                                                                                 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading
                                                                                 metrics:metrics
                                                                                   views:views]];
    /*
    [progressViewLeft addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pttPlayingCountdownLabel
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:pttPlayingInLabel
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0]];
    [progressViewLeft addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pttPlayingCountdownLabel
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:pttPlayingInLabel
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0]];
     */


    // Visual horizontal
    [progressViewLeft addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[pttPlayingInLabel]-[pttPlayingCountdownLabel(==20)]-|"
                                                                                 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline
                                                                                 metrics:metrics
                                                                                   views:views]];
    [progressViewLeft addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[pttProgressView]-|"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:metrics
                                                                                   views:views]];

    // Now for the inner danker right
    [progressViewRight addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pttCancelPlayingButton
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:nil
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                     multiplier:1
                                                                       constant:21.0]];
    [progressViewRight addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pttCancelPlayingButton
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:nil
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                     multiplier:1
                                                                       constant:21.0]];
    [progressViewRight addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pttCancelPlayingButton
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:progressViewRight
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                     multiplier:1
                                                                       constant:0]];
    [progressViewRight addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pttCancelPlayingButton
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:progressViewRight
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                     multiplier:1
                                                                       constant:0]];
```

Comment: `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` - and you are complaining that the top and bottom are cut off? In general: add constraints via the interface builder - it is infinitely better and easier to debug and design.

Comment: I am definitely complaining about that :D. Everything is created via code. I didn't use the interface builder for this view.

Comment: Okay, then unfortunately cannot help you - maybe someone with experience in reading code layout constraints can.

Comment: `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`. Key word in there is probably `Width`, whereas you appear to have problems with the *height* of the label.